# django - Adding django form fields dynamically and preserving user input

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, forms

The situation is like I have a post job form where the fields are like

1. Job Title
2. Job Description
3. Job Qualification
4. Job Requirements

*Job Title* and *Job Description* are columns in the same table called **Job**, and *Job Qualifications* and *Job Requirements* are two separate tables with names **JobQualifications** and **JobRequirements** respectively pointing ( with ForeignKey ) to the **Job** table.

The 3rd and 4th fields are dynamic with minimum one entry permitted, but user can add more qualifications and requirements after the form is rendered in the browser.

The ways in which I approach this.
We can add fields with javascript, but when user submits the form and if something goes wrong with the form and we have to re-render the form with user input still there.

I talked this with guys on #django (IRC) and what I found was actually helpful. We can user *inline-formsets* like in the **2.9.2 Adding related objects** section of the *part 7* of django tutorial, but implementing it manually will be rather complicated and involve doing some javascript.

I can't figure out how should I do this, any help is appreciated.

Thanks already

Answer (score 0):

You can create fields in form's init method under an if condition, example-

```
if request.POST:
    if req_field_exists:
         if new_field in request.POST:
            return
         else:
            new_field = forms.Charfield()
```

This will work when the user submits the form, and another field is added if the previous field is provided. this will not work asynchronously or via AJAX.